# C++ loop through objects and obtain their addresses

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

I have the following code snippet:

```
vector<shape*> triangle_ptrs;
for (auto x : triangles)
    triangle_ptrs.push_back(&x);
```

`triangle` is a class derived from `shape` class, and `triangles` is an `std::vector` of triangles:

```
std::vector<triangle> triangles;
```

I need to save the addresses of the triangles, but as I loop through the collection, their addresses seem to be the same. How do I go around this?

Comment: `x` is a copy of the triangle you are looping over. Use `auto &x` to get a reference to the original triangle and get the pointer you want.

Comment: Please extend you post with a [minimal, verifiable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `auto & x` instead of `auto x` in the ranged for loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this loop:

```
for (auto x : triangles)
    triangle_ptrs.push_back(&x);
```

which is logically equal to:

```
for ( auto it = triangles.begin(), it != triangles.end(); ++it) { 
    auto x  = *it; 
    triangle_ptrs.push_back(&x);
}
```

you make a copy in each iteration, change your loop to:

```
for (auto &x : triangles)
    triangle_ptrs.push_back(&x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the address of a local temporary variable, change the type of `x` to be `auto&` then you get a reference to the vector elements.